# Firefox Extension to Summarize CSS Selectors on a Page

Tags: html, css, jsf, eclipse-plugin, firefox-addon

I have Google'd this nine-ways-to-Sunday, but can't seem to come up with anything that fits my needs... I'm looking for a Firefox extension (and or Eclipse plug-in) that does the "opposite" of what SitePoint's handy [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) does.  Briefly, I want to be able to go to a page and get a summary of all the class and id attribute values that are specified in the HTML markup.  Dust-Me is more stylesheet-centric, in that it compares the used and unused STYLESHEET selectors to what appears on the page.  I need to find classes and ids that are specified in the page, but have no corresponding stylesheet selector, or no stylesheet at all for that matter.

The venerable [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) extension for Firefox does exactly this, EXCEPT, it's overlayed on the rendered page, which is not quite what I need.  I'd like output more akin to Dust-Me; i.e., a summarized list.

Sure, I can do this with command-line grep... except that I can't, because I'm dealing with JSF, and I wanted to see what the rendered output in the browser is.

Another reference is [PrimerCSS](http://primercss.com/).  It does "sort of" what I want, but I'm looking for a more on-the-fly, Firefox solution; and again, a list-- not a template.  [PrimerCSS](http://primercss.com/) makes you copy/paste the markup into a form on the site, and then comes up with a naked CSS stylesheet.  Useful, but not.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/css) combined with the [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) plugin would get you what you want.